# nvarchar to time conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion, nvarchar

I have to develop system which is accept data (in database) from another system. The problem I face is all DATE and TIME data is in `NVARCHAR`. I have to convert to `DATE` and `TIME` in order to calculate the duration. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Data example:

```
STR_YMD     STR_HMS
--------------------
20150101    151000
20090807    123009
20130113    145602
20090515    061700
```

How could I convert this data into following `DATETIME` data?

```
STR_DT 
--------------------
2015-01-01  15:10:00
2009-08-07  12:30:09
2013-01-13  14:56:02
2009-05-15  06:17:00
```

Hopefully someone could help me. Thanks in advance

Bet

Comment: Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(STR_YMD, 1,  4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(STR_YMD, 5,  2) + '/' +
SUBSTRING(STR_YMD, 7,  2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(STR_HMS, 1,  2) + ':' + 
SUBSTRING(STR_HMS, 3,  2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(STR_HMS, 5,  2) AS DateTime)
```

**EDIT :** You can use LEFT function to be compatible with short time formats :

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(STR_YMD, 1, 4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(STR_YMD, 5, 2) + '/' +
SUBSTRING(STR_YMD, 7, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(LEFT(STR_HMS+'000000', 6), 1, 2) + ':' +
SUBSTRING(LEFT(STR_HMS+'000000', 6), 3, 2) + ':' +
SUBSTRING(LEFT(STR_HMS+'000000', 6), 5, 2) AS DateTime)
```

Comment: It is possible but the length of the STR_HMS might be various so i have to check all variant. e.g. 1750. I think there is some convert function that i could use. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi @Bet if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.